# (Google Docs) Is it possible to protect certain cells from moving?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I own a handful of spreadsheets with dropdown menus. Sometimes people, who are responsible for filling these spreadsheets with data, accidentally move cell with dropdown menus from one column to adjacent column. This breaks the whole process of gathering data. Can I somehow protect certain cells from moving?

Spreadsheet example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvHOD-oqzP4MdHNsSGxLaHVYZGNKUmVTaVNGS1lMVEE&pli=1#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

You can script an event to check the modified column and replace with original drop-down menu from other Spreadsheet, e.g.,

```
function onEdit(e) {
 if (e.range.getColumnIndex() == 1)
  e.range.setValues(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('menu').getRange(e.range.getRowIndex(), e.range.getColumnIndex(), e.range.getNumRows(), e.range.getNumColumns() ).getValues());
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events